# jQuery html function acting asynchronous instead of synchronous

Tags: jquery

I am a bit bewildered. I have a function that calls an ajax search on keyup below.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(e) {
        $("#showPending").html("");
        if ($('#showPending').is(':empty')){
            if ( this.value.length > 2  ) {

                var search = $("#search").val();
                loadsearch(search);
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything works great except if the user types a search parameter quickly he/she will get duplicate records appended to the #showPending table. If they type slowly they will get perfect results. I was under the impression the loadsearch function will not be called until after the #showpending element is empty because it is a synchronous function. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Cheers!
**update: load search function (minimized) below:**

```
function loadsearch(search){

    $("#showPending").html("");
    
    $.ajax({
    url: "server-calls/load-search.php?callback=?",
    type: "GET",
    data: {search: search},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data, status) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var obj = data[i];
                
            $("#showPending").append('<a href="javascript:void(0);">SEARCH RESULTS </a>');
            }
        
        }                                   
    });     
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `loadsearch`?

Comment: You are removing the content of `#showPending` right before checking if empty. i.e. it will always be empty. I am not sure this resolves all your issues, but it is definitely not something you want to do.

Comment: added the load search function

Comment: Read up on how to *"throttle"* or *"debounce"* in js  to account for faster typing   and cut down on requests for every key stroke

Comment: @ZoliSzabó yeah, thats what I expected. I added that extra check to try to make sure the element is empty before ajaxing in more results. ie. I don't want duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abort the previous XHR at the beginning of calling `loadsearch`, so that the prior request doesn't go to its `success` handler:

```
let request;
function loadsearch(search){
    request?.abort();
    $("#showPending").html("");
    
    request = $.ajax({
        // ...
```

You can also send out a request only after a certain amount of time has passed since the last input, maybe 500ms:

```
let timeout;
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function (e) {
    $("#showPending").html("");
    if ($('#showPending').is(':empty')) {
        if (this.value.length > 2) {
            var search = $("#search").val();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(() => loadsearch(search), 500);
        }
    }
});
```

For the best experience, I'd recommend using both approaches together.

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you so much. Would I be correct in assuming that .html() is in fact asynchronous?? (and not synchronous as most stackoverflow users say?)

Comment: No, `html` is synchronous. The only async action here is the `$.ajax`